# XCUI Test: How does test collection happen

Tags: objective-c, xcode, testing, automated-tests

The test collection in XCUI Test happens in alphabetical order

So, if there are test like

- test_A
- test_X
- test_1A
- DISABLE_test

the order of execution is

- test_1A
- test_A
- test_X

and the DISABLE_test is not picked as it doesn't begin with **test**

I was wondering how do I intelligently name the tests to run them in order.

First solution i thought was use numbers, but

- test_1a
- test_2b
- test_10c

the tests execute in order,

- test_1a
- test_10c
- test_2b

which is not the intended order.

What is the better design?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Test collection is done by using reflection on the object to get all the method names. Im not sure if this is done via the [Objective-C runtime](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/objectivec/objective_c_runtime) in Swift test cases but its not important.

You are close with your ordering but you can observe that this is the correct alphabetical order for your test names.

```
let things:[String] = ["test-2","test-1","test-10"]
let sorted = things.sorted() 
//["test-1", "test-10", "test-2"]
```

Pad out the names to get your desired order.

```
let things:[String] = ["test-02","test-01","test-10"]
let sorted = things.sorted()
//["test-01", "test-02", "test-10"]
```

At a more structural level the requirement to run test in a particular order might indicate that the tests are not decoupled. i.e `test-10` should not depend on state setup by `test-01` or `test-02`.